# Can someone help me predict the products for this problem?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

will it be cyclic? I just don’t understand the methods to determine how to start this.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem, you should look at the modes of reactivity available.

The reactant has an electrophilic component (the alkyl chloride) and a mildly nucleophilic component (the alcohol). It has one slightly acidic hydrogen on the alcohol ($\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}} \approx 15$).

Sodium hydride is a non-nucleophilic base. This means you should immediately look for acid base reactions.

As Waylander pointed out, the best reaction is to deprotonate the alcohol with the hydride. You now have a strongly nucleophilic species in the form of an alkoxide, which can displace the chloride via an $S_{\mathrm{N}}2$ reaction. Stereochemical concerns are important here because it's a bimolecular reaction so pay careful attention to the product stereochemistry.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the pKa value for the alcohol?

Comment: You memorize it and/or look it up. Probably, here I rounded too aggressively. It should be closer to 16. @SourabhYelluru

Answer (score 0):

Sodium hydride is a strong base, strong enough to completely deprotonate the alocohol. An internal nucleophilic attack will displace chloride giving the epoxide

Comment: Will be any kind of stereochemistry inversion?

Comment: As your starting material is single isomer your product should also be